# Cannot Click or Drag Connections Inspector's item to View Controller on Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

i'm new to **iOS Development**. currently just want to produce `Hello World` Message.

However, after write update `ViewController.swift` code, i can't not drag or click any item on Controller Inspector's item

Below are Updated code of `ViewController.swift` :

```
@IBAction func showMessage(sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "My Hello Wolrd App", message: "Hello, World!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

    alert.show()

}
```

Belo are screenshot of Connections Inspectors :

[image: Connections Inspector]

any idea to solve this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Method signature like

```
@IBAction func showMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "My Hello Wolrd App", message: "Hello, World!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

    alert.show()

}
```

After changing signature try to connect from storyboard
Hope it will help you.

**Edit:-**

[image]

Comment: Hi, i've change it, but no work...stil cannot drag any item to View Controller

Comment: i have added screen short. if you not get your class from Assistant editor menu then click on Automatic to manual. select your class manually then try to connect